# ¿Es posible leer un caracter por teclado en Java?

Tags: java, teclado

Necesitaría saber cómo leer un caracter por teclado en *Java*.

Sé que se puede leer un número, o una frase, pero esta vez quisiera que lea solo un caracter, y que el sistema muestre un mensaje, inmediatamente después de presionar ese caracter, y no cuando toco <kbd>Intro</kbd>.

El siguiente código recibe un entero, luego toco <kbd>Intro</kbd>, y se guarda.

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int número = teclado.nextInt();
```

Pero lo que quiero es guardar un caracter sin presionar la tecla. ¿Es posible?

Comment: Realmente no hay un método nextChar. Si quieres ver las suposiciones de porque: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746185/why-doesnt-the-scanner-class-have-a-nextchar-method. Si quieres obtener un solo carácter puedes realizarlo con `teclado.next().charAt(0);`. Y no se porque no quieres usar la tecla Intro pero creo que no se puede realizar lo que quieres.

Comment: El problema no es Java, sino la consola que usas para ejecutar la aplicación. Debes ver alguna manera de poner la consola/terminal en modo caracter. Puedes encontrar más detalle en [esta pregunta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/1065197).

Comment: @Luiggi creo que deberías publicar como respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** es posible realizar en el modo consola.

Para más información podrias observar el siguiente [enlace en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it):

Answer (score 5):

Con la clase `Scanner` podemos encontrar diferentes funciones, como por ejemplo el capturar cadenas, números, etc:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int número = teclado.nextInt();
```

Lo siguiente toma el primer caracter de lo que ingreses:

```
char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
```

No recuerdo del todo si de esta forma te impida capturar más de un caracter, espero sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: Yo hice algo parecido con "Q Basic", le agregue un Do While el cual la condición era que el carácter nuevo fuera diferente de "Enter/Intro" y el resto lo iba agregando a una variable, al mismo tiempo iba imprimiendo carácter por carácter con una función que me dejaba imprimir en una posición especifica de la ventana, dentro del while tenia una condición de que si se digitaba backspace "borrara" la ultima letra ingresada/impresa

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta debido a que necesitas controlar cada posicion del caracter. No es posible https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44475/71456

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es posible. Te dejo por aquí un pequeño programita que te pide un carácter y luego lo muestra por pantalla.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner escaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca un carácter: ");
    char caracter;
    caracter = escaneo.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println(caracter);

}
```

En cuanto a mostrar un mensaje sin pulsar el intro se me escapa un poco. Si encuentro forma edito el mensaje y lo añado. De todas formas supongo que se podrá hacer. Con cualquier lenguaje se puede hacer cualquier cosa, aunque sea más o menos complicado, al final se saca

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
// Primero importamos la clase scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

    // Definimos el metodo main
    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception{

        // Declaramos el objeto teclado
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declaramos la variable caracter
        char caracter;

        // Mensaje al usuario para que introduzca un caracter.
        System.out.println("Introducir caracter: ");

        caracter = teclado.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: y como esto soluciona el problema planteado? recuerda que responder solo con código es de baja calidad, edita esto y explícalo

Comment: Hola Lubo, aunque este código puede resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, sería ideal que añadieras algo más de información: ¿qué es lo que hace? ¿dónde se pondría? ¿por qué/cómo soluciona el problema? Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score -2):

Lo que intentas hacer supongo que está relacionado con el **uso de eventos de teclado**. KeyAdapter te ayudaría.

Es recomendable hacer una nueva clase para el evento extendiendo la clase KeyAdapter. Para no escribir todos los métodos de la interfaz KeyListener, podrías utilizar el método `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`. [más información](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html#keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)).

Comment: La pregunta es para programas en terminal, es decir en consola. Esto no se asocia a componentes swing.