# Error al tomar la letra "s" mediante Scanner

Tags: java

Error al tomar la letra `s` mediante `Scanner`:

```
do{
    //¿Volver a jugar?
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("¿Volver a jugar?(s/n): ");
    volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println(volverjugar);
} while ( volverjugar != "s" );
```

Comment: El tipo de dato de la variable *volverjugar*  es Char o String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Cannot find symbol volverjugar - No reconoce la variable

El error se debe porqué en ningún momento declaraste el identificador `volverjugador`, es decir, el compilador nunca lo reconocerá y por esa razón te sale ese error de compilación.

Una posible solución, es declarar la variable `volverjugar` (debería de ser de tipo `string`) como local al principio del método `main`.

De ese modo, el compilador no debería mandar ningún error de sintaxis; sin embargo, tu código tiene varias fallas:

**1. En esta parte del código ocurrirá un posible bucle infinito:**

```
do{
   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
   numero = teclado.nextInt();
   System.out.println(numero);
   cont++;
} while (numero != rand );
```

Si te das cuenta, el código de arriba le seguirá pidiendo información al usuario hasta que ingrese el número correcto. El problema radica que no sabemos en que momento coincidirá el número ingresado por el usuario, con el valor que tenga `rand`. Podría ser en 10 intentos, en 1000 intentos. Para evitar este inconveniente, podríamos asignarle un límite de ingreso de números (por ejemplo, `5` intentos), de este modo, hacemos el juego más interactivo con el usuario.

En código quedaría así:

```
do{
  System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
  numero = teclado.nextInt();
  cont++;
  //Cuando el usuario haga 5 intentos, el bucle finaliza.
  if(cont == 6) break;
}while (numero != rand );
```

**2. En esta parte del código estás comparando referencias:**

```
}while (volverjugar != "si" );
```

El código de arriba lo que hará es comparar referencias a objetos, es decir, ocurrirá un bucle infinito, debido a que, las referencias (direcciones de memoria) no serán iguales.

Una posible solución, es usando el método [equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) de la clase `String`.

Entonces, con este método podremos comparar cadenas de forma segura, si el usuario ingresa `SI` o `si`, el método retornará `true` y hará que el juego comience de nuevo. Si el usuario ingresa que `NO` o `no`, devolverá `false` y esto hará que el bucle finalice (porqué la condicional no se cumplirá y por ende, el bucle rompe).

```
}while(volverjugar.equalsIgnoreCase("si") == true);
```

**3. No es necesario crear en cada iteración objetos de tipo `Scanner`.**

Estar creando objetos de tipo `Scanner`, lo único que lograras es darle más procesos al [recolector de basura](https://guru99.es/java-garbage-collection/)  de Java, debido a que, en cada repetición, deberá reservar memoria dinámicamente para un objeto y de paso, buscar el momento preciso para liberar memoria.

Una forma de optimizar esto, es guardando la referencia del objeto de tipo `Scanner` al principio del método `main`.

El código completo, con los cambios efectuados, quedaría de esta forma:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt();
        int numero;
        int cont = 0;
        String volverjugar;
        do{
            do{
                System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
                numero = teclado.nextInt();
                cont++;
                if(cont == 6) break;
            }while (numero != rand );
            System.out.println("Intentos partida:" + cont);
        //Esto limpia el bufer del teclado
        teclado.nextLine();
        //¿Volver a jugar?
        System.out.println("Volver a jugar?(si/no): ");
        volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
        cont = 0;
        }while(volverjugar.equalsIgnoreCase("si") == true);
    }
}
```

Esta línea de código:

```
teclado.nextLine();
//¿Volver a jugar?
```

Lo único que hace, es limpiar el búfer del teclado. Esto es necesario porqué como se llamó al método `nextInt` (de la clase `Scanner`), dejará el búfer sucio (con el salto de línea) y esto se lo debe limpiar, de lo contrario, cuando quieras pedir al usuario, que si quiere volver al jugar o no, no pausará el programa y como `volverjugar` valdrá `\n`, hará que la condicional: `volverjugar.equalsIgnoreCase("si") == true` dé como resultado `false`, haciendo que el juego termine sin que el usuario haya tomado la decisión de salir.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la variable es de tipo Char, ésto te funcionaría:

```
volverjugar = teclado.next().charAt(0);
```

Puede que ésto te ayude

[¿Es posible leer un caracter por teclado en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36298/es-posible-leer-un-caracter-por-teclado-en-java)

Answer (score 0):

Para recoger un **String** con Scanner debes usar método **nextLine()**.

Además cuando preguntas por consola System.out.print**ln**("¿Volver a jugar? (s/n):") fijate que es con **ln** para que de un **salto de linea** y tome la entrada el **teclado.nextLine()**. Así:

```
public static void jugarPartida(){
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("¿Volver a jugar? (s/n):");//es print con ln
    volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println(volverjugar);
}
```

Debo señalar que el método por más que te funcione, no se hace así. Primero que el Scanner no se inicializa dentro del método ya que cada vez que se llame éste se creará un nuevo objeto Scanner. Después que se debe usar dentro de un **bucle** para que se repita la acción de **jugar** mientras **volverjugar** valga **s**

Comment: Gracias. Me dice por volverjugar que "Cannot find symbol". Como que no está declarada la variable.